# Generating response validation

Tags: typescript, nswag

Hi dear NSwag community!

I'd like to extend the TS generation templates for NSwag to include validation of the response. So for example, if my (exported) DTO looks like this:

```
export interface GetListResultOfResourceDto {
    Items?: ResourceDto[] | undefined;
    MaxMatches: number;
    Skip: number;
    Take: number;
}
```

**Can NSwag supply me with all the properties I need** to extend the template to output some code like this?

```
const response = ... // Shortend example
if (response.Items === undefined || !Array.isArray(response.Items))
    throw new Error("Invalid property Items");
if (response.MaxMatches === undefined)
    throw new Error("Invalid property MaxMatches");
// And so on...
```

Writing the template wouldn't be a problem for be but I can't figure out where to get all these properties (in terms of templating) from.

Comment: You need to check the model classes in njsonschema but we might have to extend them so that validation info is exposed

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box there is no configuration option which enables this.

This might be possible by heavily manipulating the TS templates but I am still unsure if NSwags model classes supply all the information to the template to implement this.